# How to get coordinates from a Line in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to get the coordinates of a specific colored line. I need to get the values(coordinates) for the green color line. How to get them? Last time i was able to do with the aid cornerHarris method. But I think this time it's not a wise idea to use it. How can I get the coordinates of the green line?

[image]

Comment: there are two green lines. you want them both? you can find green color by using the inRange function.

Comment: yes sir both of them